# Android Studio ¿Por qué mi Dialog no muestra mis Text View?

Tags: android, android-studio, popup, dialog

**Descripción**

Estoy mostrando un diálogo (pop-up) que representa un cierre de sesión.

**Foto del dialog**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema**

El problema es que al ejecutar la app y abrir el pop-up, no se muestran ninguna de las líneas horizontales que se ven en la foto. Dichas líneas son text views de 0.1 dp con background de color. (Aclaro que nunca antes había tenido este problema con el uso de estas txt líneas)

**Adjunto foto de como se ve ejecutado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto el código XML de mi pop-up**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_cerrar_sesion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/cerrar_sesi_n"
    android:textColor="#252525"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/arimo_bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_barra0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#616161"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_cerrar_sesion"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_cerrar_sesion_lore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:fontFamily="@font/arimo"
    android:text="@string/estas_seguro"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_barra0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_barra1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#616161"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_cerrar_sesion_lore"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_separador"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_barra1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_cancelar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/seleccion_popup_chat"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:fontFamily="@font/arimo_bold"
    android:text="@string/cancelar"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="#5d4037"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_separador"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txt_cerrar_sesion_lore"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_barra1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_aceptar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/seleccion_popup_chat"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:fontFamily="@font/arimo_bold"
    android:text="@string/aceptar"
    android:textColor="#5d4037"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txt_cerrar_sesion_lore"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_separador"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_barra1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_barra2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#616161"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_cancelar"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Comment: "nunca antes había tenido este problema", pero me parece que no habìas usado CosntraintLayout verdad?

Comment: A que te referis? Claramente uso ese contenedor. Igualmente ya lo solucioné cambiando el match_parent de los text views por una medida específica.